# CSS floating elements causes other element background colors to disappear

Tags: html, css

I am testing out CSS and seeing how it works with floating elements in a horizontal menue:

```
<ul id="navlist">
    <li><a href="#">Item one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
</ul>

ul#navlist {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: cyan;
}
ul#navlist li {
    display: inline;
    background-color: pink;
}

/*ul#navlist li a {
    float:left;
}*/
```

I use the background colors to visually see what is affected. Here is the output:

[output](http://jsfiddle.net/NVRFC/)

Notice the left gap between the list items. Now when I un-comment/insert the the following line:

```
ul#navlist li a {
        float:left;
    }
```

The gap disappears (what I intended) but the background colors for both `ul` and `li` disappear. [Output](http://jsfiddle.net/jPDyb/) Why is this?

Comment: Don't float the `a`, float the containing `li`. `ul#navlist li { float: left; }` instead. http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/jPDyb/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background is despairing because the content is floating, so the parent's height gets to zero. In practical terms, the link it's just anchored on the `<li>` and not inside it, got it?!

Change the `<li>` display type to `inline-block` and, optionally, set a height for your `<li>` elements.